# How do I repurpose the context menu for reply?

Tags: c#, outlook

I have an Explorer.xml, where I found the right-click reply control to be in idMso "ContextMenuMailItem"

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
     <button idMso="Reply" onAction="Reply_RightClick"/>
</contextMenu>
```

However, when I try to set an onAction to it, the function is not being called.

```
public void Reply_RightClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
      //do something
}
```

I know the .cs file is properly set up because I have custom buttons that are properly triggering its respective function, and I know that reply button is the one I want because when I toggle visible/enable to false, it gets appropriately hidden/disabled. How can I intercept this reply? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it ever proves helpful to someone else, I managed to find a workaround to this!

First, hide the original reply button on the context menu.

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
     <button idMso="Reply" visible="false"/>
</contextMenu>
```

Then, add a custom reply button to the context menu at the same spot where you hid the reply button, with the reply icon

```
<button id="Custom_Reply" onAction="reply_click" label="Reply" insertBeforeMso="MarkAsRead" imageMso="Reply"/>
<menuSeparator id="Separator" insertBeforeMso="MarkAsRead/>
```

And after that, you will be able to do what you need to your reply button

```
public void reply_click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
     if(control.Context is Outlook.Selection)
     {
          Outlook.Selection item = control.Context as Outlook.Selection);
          if(item[1] is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
          {
               mailItem = item[1] as Outlook.MailItem;

               //do stuff to your mailitem

               //then do a .reply and display the repurposed mailitem
               Outlook.MailItem replyMail = mailItem.Reply();
               replyMail.Display();

               //don't forget to release your comobjects!
               if(replyMail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(replyMail);
               if(mailItem != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
          }
     }
}
```