# Customize contextual menus in an Outlook VSTO plugin

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I am working on an Outlook VSTO plugin.

I am (unsuccessfully) trying to customize the contextual menu that appears when you right-click on the **content** of an email. Note that most resources available online (such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee692172(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforaMailItem), which is otherwise great) explain how to customize the context menu that shows up when you click on an email item in your mail box - not when you right-click on the content of the email itself.

I have read dozens of threads... but failed to find a hint so far.

My best try so far was to retrieve the WordEditor that is in the inspector and try to access this WordEditor's command bars. But this does not work... I'd be happy to discuss workaround / other approaches / relevant resources with anyone :)

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
' So that we can have intellisense in the WordEditor object
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Public Class ThisAddIn


    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        ' Whenever a new inspector is created, let's see if we can customize its menus
        AddHandler Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers.NewExplorer, AddressOf OnNewExplorer
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnNewInspector(inspect As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector)

        If inspect IsNot Nothing Then
        ' WordEditors are only located in inspectors that have IsWordMail = true
            If inspect.IsWordMail Then
            ' ... and that have the EditorType = olEditorWord
                If inspect.EditorType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlEditorType.olEditorWord Then
                    Try
                        ' Get the WordEditor that is in the email
                        ' Always fails here - as if by the time that OnNewInspector is called, the WordEditor was not available yet
                        Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = inspect.WordEditor()
                        ' Get the right command bar (still to confirm, seen in online forums)
                        cb = doc.CommandBars("Text")
                        If cb IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim cbCtrl As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl
                            '... add a new button to the command bar
                        End If
                        ' Release COM objects from memory
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        ' This code always ends up here
                        Debug.WriteLine("exception:" & ex.Message)
                    End Try
                Else
                    Debug.WriteLine("This inspector does not have the right Editor Type")
                End If
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("This inspector is not a WordMail")
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

Best - and thanks again for your help,

JB

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960423/how-do-i-repurpose-the-context-menu-for-reply

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!

This thread, like pretty much every resource I found so far, discusses how to customize the context menu that appears when you right-click on an email in the view where you see all your emails inbox. 

What I am looking for is how to customize the context menu that appear when you right-click on an email's text section. I will edit my original question to explain this better and show what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading pane popup menu comes from Word (Outlook uses Word-light to display and edit messages). I don't think you can customize it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution, even after putting in another afternoon on various attempts and readings. You must be right: these popup menus cannot be customized.